# How to implement *ngIf to toggle(hide and show) between two components on the same page

Tags: angular, typescript, tabulator

I have two components A(app-table) and B(app-edit), and I am using Tabulator-table library to generate tables in both components. When the page is loaded it should only load table A. 'loading' Boolean value for component B is false, and only becomes true when a cell is clicked on the table, I am using callback function to set the loading value true or false. On console(using console.log) I can see the Boolean value changing from false to true on click but it doesn't change the view. that means component B never shows up on the page.

**componentA.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-schedule',
  templateUrl: './schedule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./schedule.component.scss']
})


export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit {
  public loading: boolean = true;

  constructor() {}

  openEdit(e, cell) {
    this.openEditValue = false
    console.log(this.openEditValue)
  }

  columnNames = [
    {
      title: "description",
      field: "description"
    },
    {
      title: "shortCode",
      field: "wbsElement.shortCode",
      cellClick: this.openEdit
    },
  ];
}

ngOnInit() {

}
```

**componentA.html**

```
<app-table 
    [tableRowData]= "schedule"
    [columnNames]= "columnNames"
    [tableID]= "tableID">
</app-table> 

  <div *ngIf= "loading">
    <app-edit ></app-edit>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The boolean value you are changing in  `openEdit` is called `openEditValue` but your `*ngIf` binding is to `loading`. Also, to toggle on and off, you have to [negate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)(!) the value on click.

```
public openEditValue: boolean = false;

openEdit(e, cell){
   this.openEditValue = !this.openEditValue
   console.log(this.openEditValue) 
}

// template
<div *ngIf= "openEditValue">
    <app-edit ></app-edit>
</div>
```

Comment: value is changing from true to false after making the suggested changes, but still doesn't show the component B

Comment: No error, after clicking on the cell I see the value changing from true to false nothing else

Comment: And you have made the changes to `*ngIf` ?

Comment: Yes I did. no luck

Answer (score 0):

May I Ask you to please put some working code in the question, You can see the steps from [here](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2024)

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iyyjef?file=src/app/app.component.ts) is the Solution for you problem

Component Table

```
    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Tabulator from 'tabulator-tables';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

export interface IPerson {
  id: number,
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  state: string
} // Use Interface for datatypes in Typescripts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  template: `<div id="tabulator-div"></div>`, // Html for Tabulator
  styles: []
})
export class TabulatorTableComponent implements OnInit {
  people: IPerson[] = [];
  columnNames: any[] = [];
  myTable: Tabulator;

  constructor(private storageService: StorageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.people = [
      { id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", state: "Ohio" },
      { id: 2, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe", state: "Iowa" },
      { id: 3, firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Great", state: "Hawaii" },
      { id: 4, firstName: "Ted", lastName: "Adventure", state: "Arizona" }
    ];

const self = this;
    this.myTable = new Tabulator("#tabulator-div", {
      height: 205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
      data: this.people, //assign data to table
      layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (
      autoColumns: true,
      cellClick: function (e, cell) {
        self.storageService.emitShowEdit();
      },
    });
  }
}
```